# UITableViewCell as UIView from XIB

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, xib, nscoder

I have `CustomTableViewClass` in XIB, adding it to `UITableView` like

```
class RestaurantsTableView: UITableView {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.register(UINib(nibName: "RestaurantTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "restaurantCell")
    }
}
```

and everything works fine, now I would like to use this `CustomTableViewClass` as `UIView` in some other `UIViewController`, but I do not get how to properly override its `init(coder aCoder: NSCoder)` function, cause I do not need one for `UITableView` case and when I implement it like I do for other custom XIB views it crashes with `nil`

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    let _ = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("RestaurantTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! UIView
}
```

Comment: did you assign CustomTableViewClass class in storyBoard ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is one way you can use [`contentView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623229-contentview) property of `UITableViewCell` which of type `UIView`.
So simply get RestaurantTableViewCell as you previously getting from nib then use its `contentView` to get the `UIView` from it.

```
let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("RestaurantTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! RestaurantTableViewCell
let yourView = cell.contentView
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :

```
    var views:NSArray = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Your_Xib_file", owner: self, options: nil);
    var yourView:UIView = views.objectAtIndex(0) as! UIView;
```